# What is meant by "prepared statement has pending or unread results"?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

What is written on the PHP Manual and also one comment from the manual says:

> Closes a prepared statement.
>   mysqli_stmt_close() also deallocates
>   the statement handle. If the current
>   statement has pending or unread
>   results, this function cancels them so
>   that the next query can be executed.

Comment:

> if you are repeating an statement in
>   an loop using bind_param and so on
>   inside it for a larger operation. i
>   thougt id would be good to clean it
>   with stmt->close. but it broke always
>   with an error after aprox. 250
>   operations . As i tried it with 
>   stmt->reset it worked for me.

Here I don't understand what is the meaning of "prepared statement
has pending or unread results"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An RDBMS that is running a query can return data before the entire dataset has been processed. There can also be records that it has not read yet.

Both the records that are already read and the ones that are pending must be saved in some resource in the database server, usually called a 'cursor'.

You execute the application code statement that reads these records from the server's cursor and into your application's memory, with PHP's MySQi wrappers those are the called the `fetch` methods.

Now after executing a query, you are not obliged to fetch any or all these results. So either way, after reading the results of the query or not, executing `mysqli_stmt_close()` tells the server it can discard the cursor, i.e. remove the already read records from its memory and cancel the optionally still running query.

So:

- Unread results: fetched from the database, but not read by the client.
- Pending results: records that will be included in the result set once the query runs to completion.